# How to create an Angular 6 reactive form where form groups are added and removed with buttons

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create an Angular 6 reactive form used to build json to submit to a REST API. 
The structure is something like this:

```
audioTrack:
  path: /foo.mp4
  track: 1
  actions:
    normalize: {}
    addNoise:
      level: 5
subtitleTracks:
- path: /foo.en.srt
  format: SubRip
  actions:
    convert:
      format: WebVTT
- path: /foo.es.vtt
  format: WebVTT
  actions:
    spellCheck: {}
```

So there is a single audio track and a list of subtitle tracks
Any of these tracks are optional.
I would like to encapsulate each track as a Component which has a FormGroup that is part of a single Form. Tracks are added or deleted with buttons.

I haven't been able to find any examples that do this. I've found stuff that focuses on adding and removing individual controls, but not whole form groups.

I would think this would be a typical use case, what am I missing?

If I build a static form then everything works find, but the simple act of adding and removing components to a parent component quickly becomes a mess of confusion and I just don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Form Array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). This allows you (if you are not familiar with this) to store an array of [form groups](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) that can be pushed or popped from the array stack. An example of this can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkuqww?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). I will explain what's going on.

- (1) Create a form array via the form builder or manually, depending on
  your preferences
- (2) Push groups into the array using the standard JavaScript Array [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- (3) Remove groups from the array using the [removeAt](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeAt) function on the form array class.

**Note** you need to use ngFor to iterate over your form groups in the form array. This is what allows you to visually see the dynamically created form groups added or removed from the browser.

This will look something like this:

`<div *ngFor="let track of audioTracks.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
     Your custom html here...
<div>`

Comment: Only some of my data is an array of forms. I need to be able to add/remove nodes from an arbitrary tree structure. In my example, there is only a single audioTrack. Do I have to create a single FormArray and then transform it later? I was hoping the form would resemble the target json structure

Comment: I see, not a problem. Nest the form arrays, so a form array with a group which contains another form array: FormArray > FormGroup > FormArray > FormGroup. 

In relation to your needing to needing an arbitrary tree structure, Angular doesn't support this as far as I am aware. The only structure supported for forms is the Array.

Comment: So if I have a FormGroup that has an optional child FormGroup, there is no way to add or remove the child unless it's put into a FormArray that I limit to a max size of 1, and then I have to manually transform the json later?

Comment: No, you can remove a form control from a group: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removeControl

However, to remove a group it needs to be in an array. Also can you clarify what you mean by manually transform the JSON? Why?

Comment: The whole point of the form is to create json according to the needs of an API. I can manually create a form structure that when I get the value will be exactly what I need, but if I change it to form arrays for everything then I have to use an adapter pattern to get the json I need

Comment: Sure, then use the form to create the json and then use your pattern to do the rest upon submission to the API. Is there an issue implementing it this way?

Comment: No problem. My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is FormArray. There is a tutorial in angular.io which is similar for your problem, if I understood you correctly:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms search form FormArray

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gdygpengbdl here is the code and running app for the tutorial, pick the FormArray demo. In this demo you can add Adresses for a hero, similar what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I've read the Reactive Forms tutorial and seen that demo, but I haven't figured out how to map it to my use case. I'm talking about adding/removing components into an arbitrary tree like structure. Only some of the elements are lists of regular data. That example replaces the active Hero and adds regular data in the form of addresses, but I don't see how you can add/remove the audioTrack?

Comment: i made you a stackblitz - this is what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqbr6f in this demo only an address is present in the formGroup made an add - remove functionality

Comment: I actually need the Secret Lair to be a Component itself with a FormGroup, not just a list of controls. Or at least it could contain a child FormGroup

Comment: i refreshed the stackblitz. Could you check?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4